# How to calculate the Transposed Convolution?

Tags: neural-networks, convolution, transposed-convolution

Studying for my finals in Deep learning. I'm trying to solve the following question:

> Calculate the Transposed Convolution of input $A$ with kernel $K$:
> $$
> A=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 1\\
> 0 & 1 & 0\\
> 1 & 0 & 1
> \end{pmatrix},\quad K=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\
> 1 & 1
> \end{pmatrix}
> $$

I can't seem to find the formula which is used to calculate the Transposed Convolution (found only the formula to calculate the dimension). I know that the Convolution formula is:
$$
G(i,j)=\sum_{u=-k}^{k}\sum_{v=-k}^{k}K(u,v)A(i-u,j-v)
$$
But how to calculate the Transposed Convolution?

In a [video](https://youtu.be/96_oGE8WyPg?t=217) I saw the following example:

[image]

Which is easy for $2\times2$ kernel and image to see that:

$$
\begin{align*}
&K_{0,0}\star^{T}A=2\star^{T}\begin{pmatrix}3 & 1\\
1 & 5
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}6 & 2 & 0\\
2 & 10 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}&&K_{0,1}\star^{T}A=0\star^{T}\begin{pmatrix}3 & 1\\
1 & 5
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\\&K_{0,1}\star^{T}A=4\star^{T}\begin{pmatrix}3 & 1\\
1 & 5
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 12 & 4\\
0 & 4 & 20\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}&&K_{1,1}\star^{T}A=1\star^{T}\begin{pmatrix}3 & 1\\
1 & 5
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 3 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 5
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
$$
Then you have:
$$
A'=\begin{pmatrix}6 & 2 & 0\\
2 & 10 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}0 & 12 & 4\\
0 & 4 & 20\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 3 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 5
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}6 & 14 & 4\\
2 & 17 & 21\\
0 & 1 & 5
\end{pmatrix}
$$
But I can't seem to figure how to make it for $3\times 3$ image and $2\times 2$ kernel.

I do know that the dim of the output should be $4\times 4$ because:
$$
\begin{cases}
H=(3-1)\cdot1+2-2\cdot0=4\\
W=(3-1)\cdot1+2-2\cdot0=4
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 0):

In 3x3 images, just like in 2x2, each pixel of the input is multiplied with the kernel matrix and accumulated. A naive implementation is given by [this](https://d2l.ai/chapter_computer-vision/transposed-conv.html) page:

```
def trans_conv(X, K):
    h, w = K.shape
    Y = np.zeros((X.shape[0] + h - 1, X.shape[1] + w - 1))
    for i in range(X.shape[0]):
        for j in range(X.shape[1]):
            Y[i: i + h, j: j + w] += X[i, j] * K
    return Y
```

So, every $h\times w$ block of output matrix starting at $y_{ij}$ is accumulated with $K\times x_{ij}$.

Comment: Thank you for the programmatic solution! Could this function be written mathematically?

Comment: The math. formula is the one you wrote (check bounds), i.e. convolution, where the kernel is mirrored across x and y axes and swiped over the image. The convolution in deep learning literature and the signal processing literatures are not the same unfortunately. The formula you wrote is not the same convolution used in deep learning. Here is a convolution 2d operation in Matlab (which favors the signal processing literature): https://octave-online.net/ Enter the following to the console and see the exact same output for your example:

```
X = [2 4; 0 1]; h = [3 1; 1 5]; conv2(X, h)
```