# Algorithm to calculate the transposed convolutional

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network, transposed-convolution

I'm really getting frustrated understanding the Transposed Convolution. In the previous [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/587634/how-to-calculate-the-transposed-convolution/587638?noredirect=1#comment1085967_587638) I got a good answer which contains the code for calculating the Transposed Convolution. But I'm looking for an easy algorithm to follow in order to solve this question in the exam (I can't run the code during the exam of course).

In this [blog](https://towardsdatascience.com/what-is-transposed-convolutional-layer-40e5e6e31c11) I see:

> Implementing a transposed convolutional layer can be better explained as a 4 step process
>
> Step 1: Calculate new parameters z and p’
>
> Step 2: Between each row and columns of the input, insert z number of zeros. This increases the size of the input to (2*i-1)x(2*i-1)
>
> Step 3: Pad the modified input image with p’ number of zeros
>
> Step 4: Carry out standard convolution on the image generated from step 3 with a stride length of 1

So I took the following example:
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix},\quad K=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\
1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
The size of the output should be $4\times 4$. Lets follow the steps:

1. Fill the parms we get:
   $$
   \begin{cases}
   z=s-1=1-1=0\\
   p'=k-p-1=2-0-1=1\\
   s'=1
   \end{cases}
   $$
2. We got $z=0$ so the matrix remains:
   $$
   A'=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 1\\
   0 & 1 & 0\\
   1 & 0 & 1
   \end{pmatrix}
   $$
3. We add padding $p'=1$ so:
   $$
   A''=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
   0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
   0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
   0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
   \end{pmatrix}
   $$
4. imply convoluation:
   $$
   A''\star K=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
   0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
   0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
   0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
   \end{pmatrix}\star\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\
   1 & 1
   \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
   0 & 2 & 1 & 1\\
   1 & 1 & 2 & 1\\
   0 & 1 & 0 & 1
   \end{pmatrix}
   $$

Using [Octave](https://octave-online.net/) I should get:

> X = [1 0 1; 0 1 0; 1 0 1]; h = [1 0; 1 1]; conv2(X, h)
>
> ans =
>
> 1   0   1   0
>
> 1   2   1   1
>
> 1   1   2   0
>
> 1   1   1   1

Which is almost what I got! But it's actually the tranpose of the matrix. So it's either:

1. I'm doing something wrong.
2. There is a missing step in the algorithm to return the transpose of the matrix.
3. The algorithm does not actually work.

I tried another example (same example as in the previous thread):
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}2 & 4\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix},\quad K=\begin{pmatrix}3 & 1\\
1 & 5
\end{pmatrix}
$$

The answer should be:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}6 & 14 & 4\\
2 & 17 & 21\\
0 & 1 & 5
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Lets follow the algorithm one more time. In the first step we get:
$$
\begin{cases}
z=s-1=1-1=0\\
p'=k-p-1=2-0-1=1\\
s'=1
\end{cases}
$$
So the matrix remains:
$$
A'=\begin{pmatrix}2 & 4\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
We have $p'=1$ so the matrix becomes $4\times 4$:
$$
A''=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 2 & 4 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Now lets try the convolution:
$$
A''\star K=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 2 & 4 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\star\begin{pmatrix}3 & 1\\
1 & 5
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}10 & 22 & 4\\
2 & 15 & 13\\
0 & 1 & 3
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Now even the transpose is not the right answer. Is this algorithm valid? If not, can you please suggest an algorithm to manually follow? The algorithm given in code in previous question is "hard" to follow on hand. So how to solve it?

Comment: Why was the question closed? The referenced topic is mine and actually mentioned at the start of this topic.

Comment: It does not raise any additional statistical issues.  It's solely about a numerical algorithm.